# How to create dynamic Orderby statement on child list object in ef core

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I am trying to create the orderby dynamically based on the sort direction

```
public class Item
{   
    public Guid ItemId {get; set;}
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public List<ItemProductType> ItemProductTypes {get; set;}
}
public class ItemProductType
{
    public Guid ItemId {get; set;}
    public Guid ProductTypeId {get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
public class ProductType
{   
    public Guid ProductTypeId {get; set;}
    public string ProductTypeName { get; set; }
    public List<ItemProductType> ItemProductTypes {get; set;}
}
```

I need to create a orderby statement on the item table like

```
_context.Items.Include(a => a.ItemProductTypes)
    .ThenInclude(a => a.ProductType)        
    .OrderBy(a => 
        a.ItemProductTypes.OrderBy(b => b.ProductType.ProductTypeName)
            .Select(c => c.ProductType.ProductTypeName)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    ).ToListAsync();
```

Above code is working but I need to change orderby ascending or descending based on the Sortdirection from ColumnHeader click.

i tried using OrderBySortDynamic extension method on Queryable to get the orderby or orderbydescending dynamically

```
public static IQueryable<t> OrderBySortDynamic<t, TKey>(this IQueryable<t> query, Expression<Func<t, TKey>> keySelector, bool sortDescending) 
{ 
    string command = "OrderBy"; 
    if (sortDescending) 
    { 
        command = "OrderByDescending"; 
    } 

    Expression resultExpression = Expression.Call( 
        typeof(Queryable), 
        command, 
        new[] { typeof(t), keySelector.ReturnType },
        query.Expression, 
        Expression.Quote(keySelector));
    return query.Provider.CreateQuery<t>(resultExpression); 
}
```

how can i create an extension method for performing orderby dynamically  on the child navigationproperty which a.ItemProductTypes.**OrderBy**(b=>b.ProductType.ProductTypeName). I tried updating the above extension method with Ienumerable but it does not work.

Comment: Write working query without your dynamic realization. It is hard to understand goal.

Comment: I need to order the parent entity(item) based on the navigationproperties(itemtype) child(type.typename) and i need to perform sorting dynamically

Comment: Show working non-dynamic query.

Comment: _context.Items.Include(a => a.ItemProductTypes)
    .ThenInclude(a => a.ProductType)        
    .OrderBy(a => 
        a.ItemProductTypes.OrderBy(b => b.ProductType.ProductTypeName)
            .Select(c => c.ProductType.ProductTypeName)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    ).ToListAsync();

this linq is working

Comment: This query even do not compile and will not work either. Update question with working non dynamic query and show which part should be dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to consider is that custom extension methods cannot be used inside expression tree. e.g. here

```cs
.OrderBy(a => 
    a.ItemProductTypes.OrderBy(b => b.ProductType.ProductTypeName)
        .Select(c => c.ProductType.ProductTypeName)
        .FirstOrDefault()
)
```

you can use custom method in place of the outer `OrderBy`, but not for the inner - everything after `a =>` is part of the expression tree and must be well known method / property, because the methods/properties inside the expression tree in general are never called, but processed by the query expression translator.

With that being said, let see what we can do with your issue. The outer `OrderBy` can be replaced with the custom extension method. But the one you provided is overcomplicated and not really dynamic - all it does is to call either `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` passing the ready provided arguments. So it could be simplified as (basically the same signature as `OrderBy` with additional `bool` parameter):

```cs
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T, TKey>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector,
    bool descending
) => descending ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector) : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
```

This would work if the selector uses single value (either direct or indirect via reference navigation property). In order to handle the inner `OrderBy`, you'd need another custom method receiving the necessary parts as arguments.

In this expression

```cs
a => a.ItemProductTypes
    .OrderBy(b => b.ProductType.ProductTypeName)
    .Select(c => c.ProductType.ProductTypeName)
    .FirstOrDefault()
)
```

the customizable parts are `a.ItemProductTypes` for selecting inner enumerable from the outer "object", and `b => b.ProductType.ProductTypeName` to select the inner key for ordering.

So the second custom method would be like this:

```cs
public static IOrderedQueryable<TOuter> OrderBy<TOuter, TInner, TKey>(
    this IQueryable<TOuter> source,
    Expression<Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>>> innerSelector,
    Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector,
    bool descending
)
{
    var innerOrderBy = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable),
        descending ? nameof(Enumerable.OrderByDescending) : nameof(Enumerable.OrderBy),
        new[] { typeof(TInner), typeof(TKey) },
        innerSelector.Body,
        innerKeySelector
    );

    var innerSelect = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable),
        nameof(Enumerable.Select),
        new[] { typeof(TInner), typeof(TKey) },
        innerOrderBy,
        innerKeySelector
    );

    var innerFirstOrDefault = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable),
        nameof(Enumerable.FirstOrDefault),
        new[] { typeof(TKey) },
        innerSelect
    );

    var outerKeySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TOuter, TKey>>(
        innerFirstOrDefault,
        innerSelector.Parameters
    );

    return source.OrderBy(outerKeySelector, descending);
}
```

Here the implementation has to use `Expression` class methods to compose a key selector to be passed to the previous custom extension method. All you need to know is that these methods are static, the containing class, the method name,  generic type arguments and parameters. And that they are called in opposite order of what is provided by the C# extension method syntax sugar, i.e.

```cs
OrderBy(...).Select(...).FirstOrDefault()
```

is actually

```cs
FirstOrDefault(Select(OrderBy(...), ...))
```

Now you can use the second extension method in your query:

```cs
var query = _context.Items
    .Include(a => a.ItemProductTypes)
        .ThenInclude(a => a.ProductType)
    .OrderBy(
        a => a.ItemProductTypes,
        b => b.ProductType.ProductTypeName,
        descending: true // pass your criteria here
    );
```

---

Another possible solution is to write your query for ascending order (like in the example), and then use custom `ExpressionVisitor` to replace all `OrderBy` calls with `OrderByDescending` - something like `string.Replace`, but with expressions.

Following is a sample implementation of the above:

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> SwitchOrderBy<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    bool descending
)
{
    if (!descending) return source;
    var expression = new OrderBySwitcher().Visit(source.Expression);
    if (source.Expression == expression) return source;
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
}

class OrderBySwitcher : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if ((node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Enumerable)
            || node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable))
            && node.Method.Name == nameof(Enumerable.OrderBy))
        {
            var args = new Expression[node.Arguments.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
                args[i] = Visit(node.Arguments[i]);
            return Expression.Call(
                node.Method.DeclaringType,
                nameof(Enumerable.OrderByDescending),
                node.Method.GetGenericArguments(),
                args
            );
        }
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}
```

and sample usage

```cs
var query = _context.Items
    .Include(a => a.ItemProductTypes)
        .ThenInclude(a => a.ProductType)
    .OrderBy(a => a.ItemProductTypes
        .OrderBy(b => b.ProductType.ProductTypeName)
        .Select(c => c.ProductType.ProductTypeName)
        .FirstOrDefault()
    )
    // everything down to here is same as in the original query
    .SwitchOrderBy(descending: true); // pass your criteria here
```